# Why the difference between Wall-E's and EVE's looks and technological standards?

Tags: plot-explanation, wall-e

In WALL-E, according to the president's addresses EVE was part of the Axiom's crew since it first left Earth, meaning that she and WALL-E would have been manufactured around the same time since he was intended to start cleaning the planet up right after humanity evacuated.

Why then do the two have such a major difference in their looks and technological standards if they were both intended for roughly the same behind the scenes purpose (at least in terms of wandering around wastelands and looking through trash)?

Comment: Been a while since I saw WALL-E.  What makes you think they are intended for the same purpose?  WALL-E is an industrial cleanup robot.  EVE seems to be a scientific research device ... looking for signs of life?

Comment: WALL-E is designed to compact trash. And had been operating on his own for centuries. Of course he isn't going to look the nicest. He was one of probably millions of bots mass produced to be able to navigate trash in order to clean up. Why would he look and behave the same as EVE?

Comment: It's never mentioned that EVE was manufactured at same time as WALL-E, EVE could be newly generated just before starting the journey. As Ian and SixandSeven8ths mentioned, their purposes are different. it's basic udnerstanding. Basically being a mammal, there's Humans and Dolphins which have completely different looks. mainly because their living environments are different, challenges they have to face, day to day tasks, activities are different. same goes here for those two robots

Answer (score 9):

There are many gaps in your assumptions.

- Who says Wall-E was built at the same time as EVE? Maybe Wall-E was an outdated model at the time of Axiom's departure.
- Who says the Axiom has not updated its technology as it went? For example, the hover chairs may have been created afterwards and not as the initial launch plan.
- Who says Wall-E and EVE were built by the same company with the same quality standards and access to technology? (*Edit: they were built by the same company, but given it's the only global company, it stands to reason that the company divisions around the world don't all work with the same technology or standards*)

And as the fourth and most important point, there's still their vastly different environments and purposes.

Wall-E is built for tough and dirty work. His design follows that of [construction vehicles (link)](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9E9YK5X7Cto/maxresdefault.jpg). Tough, built to last, and built to be easily fixed by a mechanic in the field.
We see this happen when EVE rebuilds Wall-E. Spare components were available and easy to swap, because Wall-E was built to be repaired while out in the field without specialized mechanics nearby.

EVE, however, is not built for tough and dirty work. She's not expected to physically interact with rubble day in, day out. She also has no easily replaceable parts and is much more a "black box" in terms of how she is built and how her components operate. Your average Joe plumber won't be able to fix EVE with some spare parts and a screwdriver. When EVE breaks down, the Axiom either has a highly specialized process for taking her apart and fixing her, or may even just scrap her and build a new EVE. EVE is not built to be repaired while out in the field.

Different purposes lead to very different builds. Looking at cars instead of robots, look at the vast differences between a [sedan (link)](https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1280x720/cw/ec/21686/Jaguar-XJ-L-Right-Front-Three-Quarter-64990.jpg?wm=0&t=175455253&t=175455253&q=100), a [mining truck (link)](http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Caterpillar/C785388?$cc-g$) and an [airplane (link)](https://www.aviationcv.com/aviation-blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Boeings-New-Planes-are-Fuel-Savers.png). Very different vehicles, yet they are all vehicles of some sort built in roughly the same period with roughly the same access to technology.

Comment: There was only one global mega-company, Buy 'N' Large, so they were made by the same company.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Doesn't mean it's the same division, but good point that is is the same company. I'll amend that.

Comment: Also, the Axiom has large versions of WALL-E in their junk bay so the difference is definitely deliberate.